# How is the problem of sorting in contiguous runs called?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, reference-request, sorting

I am having a bit of brain fail and I can't remeber the name of the following problem (so I can find some literature around it...).

> Given a sequence of values, sort it in a way that equal elements are compacted in runs (contiguous subsequences of identical elements).

For instance:

$$
\{1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3\} \rightarrow \{ 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1 \}
$$

The runs are not otherwise sorted -- only equality comparison is required, not ordering; and they're compacted (there should not be two different runs containing equal elements).

Comment: What about "counting"?

Comment: Why isn't the sorted array $\{1,1,4,2,2,3\}$? If the elements are not sorted the basic logic will be to check for the current element and swap all elements which are identical to it.

Comment: @Raphael: it's not exactly counting -- elements in the same run can be different by other means; for instance, a sequence of "employees" arranged in runs by "year of birth".

Comment: @Sagnik: sure, sorting would lead to a solution, however it requires an ordering (which is not necessary in the formulation of the problem above), and might *possibly* be less efficient...

Comment: In distributed environments data is typically partitioned by a hash so that identical keys are stored on the same node; is that the type of situation you're thinking of?  In that case the runs are on different nodes.  The map phase in map-reduce is similar.

Comment: @KWillets: yes, the kind of bucketing that one does in that scenario (or in general when using a hash table and chaining) is very similar... but then I want the runs back!

Comment: Another idea would be "grouping".

Comment: For lack of a better idea, I've called such _clustering_ (if to avoid the connotation with SQL GROUP BY being used for aggregation).

Answer (score 1):

Gopan et al. seem to define a more general problem and call it *array partitioning* [1].

> The goals of array partitioning are twofold.  First, we
> would like to isolate in separate groups [...]
> we partition an array so that each element whose index is equal to
> the value of any of the vari ables in the set is placed in a group by
> itself. [...]
>
> [W]e partition each array $A \in Array$ by grouping together elements of $A$
> for which all partitioning functions in $\Pi_A$ evaluate to the same values.

I have not dug into how their formal framework captures your problem and it may not even do so. Still, I think the general idea is close enough to use the word.

Come to think of it, Quicksort-style partitioning is related as well: you want to partition w.r.t. identify, in Quicksort we partition w.r.t. equivalence classes induced by some pivots.

---

1. [A framework for numeric analysis of array operations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1047659.1040333) by D. Gopan, T. Reps and M. Sagiv (2005) [[preprint](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wpis/papers/popl05_naao.pdf)]